# Rails how can i show only enable clients

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, boolean, relationship

i I have 2 controllers client and sales what i need to show in my select options only clients where enable = true in my conttroler sales? enable is a boolean.

now in my new.html.slim in view SALES

```
== render 'form'
```

now in my _form.html.slim  in view Sales

```
.form-inputs  
= f.association :client
```

What i need?

Comment: Is `enable` a boolean field in `clients` table?

Comment: yes is enable  i need to list only clients where enable is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `enable` is a boolean field in `clients` table, you can just specify the `collection` option in `association` method as below:

```
= f.association :client, collection: Client.where(enable: true)
```